# Prevent a function from being called in a certain section of code

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, is there any way to prevent a function from being called in a certain section of code? I want to make sure that the function "alert" is not called in a specific section of code.

```
alert("Hi!"); //this should work normally
var al = alert
//the function "alert" cannot be called after this point

preventFunctionFromBeingCalled(alert, "Do not use alert here: use the abbreviation 'al' instead.");

alert("Hi!"); //this should throw an error, because "console.log" should be used instead here
allowFunctionToBeCalled(alert);
//the function "alert" can be called after this point
alert("Hi!"); //this should work normally
```

In this case, how should I implement the functions `allowFunctionToBeCalled` and `preventFunctionFromBeingCalled`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *sort of* achieve this like so:

```
window._alert = window.alert;
window.alert = function() {throw new Error("Do not use alert here, use console.log instead");};

// later:
window.alert = window._alert;
delete window._alert;
```

But it is major hax.

Comment: If you're inside non-global scope, you can probably get away with just masking alert with a local variable

Comment: Nope.  It's pretty uncommon for someone to actually specify `window.alert`, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = alert; //save the alert function
alert = function(){}; //change to a function you want (you can throw an error in it)
alert("something"); //this will call the empty function bellow
alert = a; //change alert back to it's original function
```

Comment: or event better... `alert = console.log`

Answer (score 0):

you can find Why "window.alert()" over "alert()"? here. http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/832371-why-window-alert-over-alerthere

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily reassign `window.alert` to a do-nothing function and hide its original value in a local variable:

```
// replace alert
var _alert = window.alert;
window.alert = function() {};

// code here can't call alert
// code in this closure can't even access the saved version of window.alert
(function() {
    alert("hello1");
})();

// restore alert
window.alert = _alert;

// code here can call alert
(function() {
    alert("hello2");
})();
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/mGC3x/